# EV Tax credit - Modified Adjustable Income if you were not a tax resident of US for 2023

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident

I was a Canadian resident for the last 3 years (including 2023) but I would have US income (W2) through company stocks and file US taxes using 1040NR.

In 2024, I moved to the US and will be a resident for tax purposes. I am planning to buy an EV and want to make sure I qualify based on my 2023 US income (about 15,000 of income). My 2023 US income was under 150K and is reported on 1040NR. Because I was based in Canada in 2023, I will pay 2023 taxes on my Canadian income to Canada.

If I buy an EV in 2024:

1. Can I use the US income of $15,000 from 2023 on my 1040NR to be eligible for the tax rebate? I cannot use my 2024 income because it exceeds $150,000.
2. As part of the MAGI (Modified Adjusted Gross Income), IRS would consider foreign income from Form 2555 (Source - https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/topic-e-frequently-asked-questions-about-the-income-and-price-limitations-for-previously-owned-clean-vehicles). But, since my primary residence was in Canada and US has a tax treaty, I did not have to pay taxes to US on income outside the US. I did not have to file Form 2555 for foreign income. Should my Canadian income be included in the MAGI for the eligibility of EV tax credits based on $150,000 limit?

Comment: I'll close it again, because it's the same question now. If something not clear - please ask what's not clear